# Can't uninstall Anaconda using "rm -rf ~/anaconda3"

Tags: python, anaconda

I am trying to leave only the native Python on my Mac but the Anaconda isn't getting uninstalled.

When I run

```
which -a python python3
```

I get 3 directories:

```
/anaconda3/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
/anaconda3/bin/python3
```

Then, to delete, I run

```
rm -rf ~/anaconda3
```

However, I keep getting the same 3 directories

```
/anaconda3/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
/anaconda3/bin/python3
```

Any ideas on how to leave only the native "/usr/bin/python" folder?

Comment: Is your conda environment still active?

Answer (score 1):

`/anaconda3` and `~/anaconda3` are two different directories. `~` means "start at the current user's home directory". `/` is the root of the filesystem. To do what you're trying to accomplish, you need `rm -rf /anaconda3`. That said, you'll need to run as root (ie with sudo), and even typing `rm -rf /` is VERY dangerous as root. You could accidentally delete your entire filesystem. Be careful...

You probably shouldn't have anaconda installed in your root in the first place. By default it usually goes to `~` in my experience.

Comment: Thanks @anderspitman, I am not sure why it was installed there. It seems to be gone now. :)